# this.controllerFor() in not a function

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In one of the views in my ember 1.10.1 app, while am trying to get controller for that particular view am getting error "this.controllerFor()" is not a function. My view's code is something like,

```
didInsertElement: function () {
               var self = this,
               controller = self.controllerFor('favorites'); 
               ---some code---
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ember.View](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html) doesnt have a controllerFor method.

Comment: And Ember.View is deprecated